# How to calculate efficiently the variance or standard deviation given a counter of numbers?

Tags: python, numpy, variance

Given for example the next histogram and the bins:

```py
import numpy as np
hist = np.array([1,1,2,1,2])
bins = np.array([0,1,2,3,4 ])
```

¿What is the most efficient way to calculate the variance?
One way would be to recreate the array and pass it to the `np.var` function:

```py
import numpy as np
np.var(np.array([0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]))
```

However, I think this is not very efficient.

Comment: Can you just rewrite the variance/std formula?

Comment: Sure If I end up with the variance @QuangHoang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can just rewrite the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance):

```
counts  = hist.sum()
mean = (hist*bins).sum() / counts

sum_squares = (bins**2 * hist).sum()
var = sum_squares/counts - mean ** 2

# test
np.isclose(var, np.var(np.repeat(bins, hist)))
```

Output `True`.

Comment: @DaniMesejo Yes, from the names, and from the population that OP posted,  `hist` should be the counts for each `bins`.

Comment: @DaniMesejo haha, true, I didn't even realized that. I was just looking up to 5 `3`, not 3 `5`.

Comment: I think you are messing up `hist` and `bins`. Hist is usually the counts, bins are the values. Anyway, if you insists that `bins` are the counts, then just swap `hist` and `bins` in my code.

Comment: @QuangHoang why doing this loses float precision?

Comment: floating_point_precision `a + a + a + a` might be different from `(a + a) + (a + a)` and from `a * 4`.

Comment: @QuangHoang this new question I just made could be interesting for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69759451/how-to-implement-vectorized-otsu-without-losing-precision-in-python